# Create HTML/JS matrix in django template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a view which returns this data in dictionary form:

```
{('ACCOUNTS', 'Staff'): 8, ('ACCOUNTS', 'TOA'): 3, ('HR', 'Officer'): 4, ('HR', 'Staff'): 1}
```

I need to convert this dictionary to a matrix in django template. something like this:

```
           Staff     Officer      TOA
ACCOUNTS    8           0          3

HR          1           4          0
```

please note the dictionary could be any longer.

models.py:

```py
class EmployeeMealRequest(models.Model):

    Dept = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True,null=True)
    EmpCategory = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```py
def reports(request, download=None):
    rows = EmployeeMealRequest.objects.all().order_by('Dept')
    myFilter = EmployeeMealRequestFilter(request.GET, queryset=rows)
    rows = myFilter.qs
    context = {
        'rows': rows,
        'filter': myFilter,

    }
    if download == str(1):
        data = EmployeeMealRequest.objects.filter(
            Att_date__gt=today).values(
                'EmpCategory',
                'Dept',).annotate(
                    total=Count('Dept')
                )
        d = {}
        categories = []
        depatments = []
        for i in data:
            d[( i.get('Dept'), i.get('EmpCategory') )] = i.get('total')
        context['data'] = d


    return render(request, 'account/download.html', context)
```

Comment: share the code of you model

Comment: @BelhadjerSamir I have added my model and view code.

Comment: maybe an html table?

Comment: @marmeladze Yes, HTML table would work, but I am having a hard time creating it, cause the dictionary could be any longer, it may contain thousands of dictionaries. I am trying to loop through but not getting the desired output.